# How to convert C++ v8 string to C compatible unsigned char?

Tags: c++, c, string, v8, native-module

```
typedef unsigned char   DL_UINT8;
```

--

```
if (info[0]->IsArray()) {
    v8::Handle<v8::Array> messageFields = v8::Handle<v8::Array>::Cast(info[0]);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < messageFields->Length(); i++) {
      v8::Handle<v8::Array> messageField = v8::Handle<v8::Array>::Cast(messageFields->Get(i));

      DL_UINT16 messageFieldPosition = (DL_UINT16)messageField->Get(0)->Uint32Value();
      const v8::String::Utf8Value _messageFieldValue(messageField->Get(1)->ToString());
      // how to convert?
      const DL_UINT8 messageFieldValue = (DL_UINT8)(_messageFieldValue); 

      //(DL_UINT16 iField, const DL_UINT8 *iDataStr)
      (void)DL_ISO8583_MSG_SetField_Str( messageFieldPosition, messageFieldValue, &isoMsg);
    }
}
```

I need help with converting `String` value in this line

```
const DL_UINT8 messageFieldValue = (DL_UINT8)(_messageFieldValue);
```

Comment: I don't know v8, but I wonder if your cast should be (DL_UINT8*) and messageFieldValue should of type DL_UINT8*.